# Fixing encoding of ID3 tags with mutagen

Tags: python, id3, mutagen

I'm trying to fix encoding of ID3 tags so that my `Nokia Lumia 630` with `windows 8` onboard would display correctly Cyrillic letters. I'm doing this [with `mutagen`](https://superuser.com/a/90491/185665):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import mutagen.id3

for path in [u'Sergei Babkin - Aleksandr [pleer.com].mp3']:
    id3 = mutagen.id3.ID3(path)
    for key, value in id3.items():
        if key in ['TIT2', 'TPE1']:
            value.text = [u'тест']
            value.encoding = 1
    id3.save()
```

Originally, some songs were displayed correctly. After my experiments, even those doesn't have readable names now. But not much has changed. Namely, `mid3v2`'s output was like this:

```
$ mid3v2 --list-raw Sergei\ Babkin\ -\ Aleksandr\ \[pleer.com\].mp3 
Raw IDv2 tag info for Sergei Babkin - Aleksandr [pleer.com].mp3
TYER(encoding=1, text=[u'2007'])
TIT2(encoding=1, text=[u'\u0410\u043b\u0435\u043a\u0441\u0430\u043d\u0434\u0440']) 
USLT(encoding=0, lang='eng', desc=u'', text=u' ') 
TRCK(encoding=1, text=[u'9']) 
TPE1(encoding=1, text=[u'\u0421\u0435\u0440\u0433\u0435\u0439 \u0411\u0430\u0431\u043a\u0438\u043d']) 
TALB(encoding=1, text=[u'\u041c\u043e\u0442\u043e\u0440'])
TCON(encoding=1, text=[u'(12)Other'])
```

(That's why I'm setting `value.encoding = 1` in my script, but I tried encoding `3` as well.) And now it's like this:

```
$ mid3v2 --list-raw Sergei\ Babkin\ -\ Aleksandr\ \[pleer.com\].mp3 
Raw IDv2 tag info for Sergei Babkin - Aleksandr [pleer.com].mp3 
TDRC(encoding=0, text=[u'2007']) 
TIT2(encoding=1, text=[u'\u0410\u043b\u0435\u043a\u0441\u0430\u043d\u0434\u0440']) 
USLT(encoding=0, lang='eng', desc=u'', text=u' ') 
TRCK(encoding=1, text=[u'9']) 
TPE1(encoding=1, text=[u'\u0421\u0435\u0440\u0433\u0435\u0439 \u0411\u0430\u0431\u043a\u0438\u043d']) 
TALB(encoding=1, text=[u'\u041c\u043e\u0442\u043e\u0440'])
TCON(encoding=1, text=[u'Other'])
```

Not sure what could have changed `TCON`. Additionally, `mp3info` now says:

```
$ mp3info Sergei\ Babkin\ -\ Aleksandr\ \[pleer.com\].mp3
File: /home/yuri/Downloads/music/бабкин/Sergei Babkin - Aleksandr [pleer.com].mp3
Title:   ????                           Track: 9
Artist:  ????
Album:   ?????                          Year:  2007
Comment:                                Genre: Other [12]
```

It displayed Cyrillic letters before using `mutagen`.

So, is there a way to find out exact encoding of what is in ID3 tags? Could you possibly know how to make it work? What am I doing wrong?

**UPD** I've got an mp3 file which my mobile phone displays correctly. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far I ran across the following issues. The first one, my phone doesn't deal with id3v2.4 tags properly (the Music app of Windows 8 that is). Saving as id3v2.3 helps. As Wikipedia [says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3#ID3v2):

> Windows Explorer and Windows Media Player cannot handle ID3v2.4 tags in any version, up to and including Windows 8 / Windows Media Player 12. Windows can understand ID3v2 up to and including version 2.3.[13][14]

The second one is that I had [one](http://pleer.com/tracks/4637630fRcg) [file](http://s7.pleer.com/0042fcbeb77d4fcf6f22cce1ca00a960ceece84879fb2254b35b1a3b6ce800a040fa4bc280c30122f32d7345d48e3f94ea6dfd998c395f71d06b9d57a810d7650e45ee750b7e/ccb5ce3e10.mp3) with garbage at the beginning (http headers). Windows didn't mind it, and could see the `id3v2` tag after the headers. Which was not the case with `puddletag` I used to edit the tags. So it added one more `id3v2` tag before the headers. But Windows ignored the first `id3v2` tag. (The second one overrode the first one?) Additionally, the artist was not present in the second `id3v2` tag, so it took it from `id3v1` tag at the end of the file (which was added by `puddletag` by the way). For more details see this [bitbucket issue](https://bitbucket.org/lazka/mutagen/issue/225/mutagen-breaks-encoding).

And here are some scripts which might come in handy:

`fix-encoding.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import sys
import mutagen.id3
id3 = mutagen.id3.ID3(sys.argv[1])
id3.save(v2_version=3)
```

`dump-id3.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import sys
import mutagen.id3
id3 = mutagen.id3.ID3(sys.argv[1])
print id3.version
for key, value in id3.items():
    if key in ['TIT2', 'TPE1']:
        print value.encoding, ', '.join(value.text).encode('utf8')
```

Usage:

```
$ find ~/Music -name '*.mp3' -exec ./dump-id3.py \;
$ find ~/Music -name '*.mp3' -exec bash -c './fix-encoding.py "$1" && mid3v2 --delete-v1 "$1"' -- {} \;
$ mid3v2 --list-raw PATH   # for completeness
```

P.S. `mp3info` [doesn't support](https://bitbucket.org/lazka/mutagen/issue/225/mutagen-breaks-encoding#comment-18479349) neither `unicode` nor `id3v2`.

P.S. Some [useful](http://id3.org/Developer%20Information) [links](http://mpgedit.org/mpgedit/mpeg_format/mpeghdr.htm) concerning [`mp3`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3#File_structure) [format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3).

Comment: mid3iconv does the job very well.
Example: mid3iconv -d -e cp1250 --dry-run *.mp3
(https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/man/mid3iconv.html)